# Multiple components stories with Lit Element + Storybook

Tags: storybook, lit-element

I have a *Sidebar* component written with Lit Element that includes many *SidebarSection* subcomponents to render different sections of the sidebar, and I'm trying to write a story with Storybook as shown in this page: [Stories for multiple components](https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/workflows/stories-for-multiple-components), but the doc does not exist yet for Web Components and I can only find React code. I'm trying to adapt to make it work with Lit but no solution has been found.